# I want to divide model's component by another component in .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Here is my model:

```
int YearNo { get; set; }
double Nights { get; set; }
double Visits { get; set; }
```

I want to divide Nights on Visits to get per night in a year and then return it by API.
this is my repository:

```
var datas = mapper.Map<List<ILocalDefaultIndicatorNights>>(records);

    List<ILocalDefaultIndicatorNights> filteredData = new List<ILocalDefaultIndicatorNights>();
    for (int i = 0; i < datas.Count; i++)
    {
        
        if (!filteredData.Exists(o => o.YearNo == datas[i].YearNo))
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < datas.Count; x++)
            {
                if (datas[i].YearNo == datas[x].YearNo && datas[i] != datas[x])
                {
                    datas[i].Visits += datas[x].Visits;
                    var obj = filteredData.FirstOrDefault(o => o.YearNo == datas[i].YearNo);
                    if (obj != null)
                        obj.Visits = datas[i].Visits;
                    else
                        filteredData.Add(datas[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredData.OrderBy(i => i.YearNo).ToList();
```

How is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

When I understand you right, then you want to do something like the following. But first I think your code could also be expressed like this:

```
List<LocalDefaultIndicatorNights> visitsPerYear = datas
    .GroupBy(x => x.YearNo)
    .Select(g => new LocalDefaultIndicatorNights()
    {
        YearNo = g.Key,
        Nights = g.First().Nights,
        Visits = g.Select(x1 => x1.Visits).Sum(),
    })
    .OrderBy(y => y.YearNo)
    .ToList();
```

The visits per night in each year then can be calculated like this:

```
Dictionary<int, double> visitsPerNightsForEachYear = visitsPerYear.Select(v =>
{
    double visitsPerNights = v.Visits / v.Nights;
    return new KeyValuePair<int, double>(v.YearNo, visitsPerNights);
})
.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```